# Python for items list, to indivdual string?

Tags: python, list, glob

Just wondering if someone can be kind enough to tell me what I am doing wrong.
working on a bit of code, with use with my cherrypy project

```
import glob
import os

def get_html(apath):
    print (apath)
    fhtml = open(apath,'r')
    data = fhtml.read()

    return data


article_path  = os.getcwd() +'/articles/*.html'
myArticles = [glob.glob(article_path)]

print len(myArticles)

for items in myArticles:
    get_html(items)
```

Results in:

```
['/home/sd/Documents/projects/cherryweb/articles/Module 5-Exploitation Techniques And Exercise.pdf.html']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fntest.py", line 22, in <module>
    get_html(items)
  File "fntest.py", line 10, in get_html
    fhtml = open(apath,'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

I assume its because the filename I'm passing has the ['  and '] from list on the string,
I could write a function to trim these parts off, but it that the only option, or am I doing something stupid.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myArticles = [glob.glob(article_path)]
```

should  be:

```
myArticles = glob.glob(article_path)
```

`glob.glob` returns a list, by adding `[]` around it you made it a list of list.

So, in this loop:

```
for items in myArticles:
    get_html(items)
```

you actually passed the whole list to `get_html` and `open` raised that error.

Demo:

```
>>> open([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-242-013dc85bc958>", line 1, in <module>
    open([])
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```